# Defining constant variable in Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook in which there is a step to use get_url to download a file

```
  - name: Download file
    get_url:
      url: https://website.com/file.sh
      dest: /tmp/file.sh
      mode: 0777
```

I don't want to put the hard-coded URL in a task. Instead I would like to make it as a constant variable like as follows

```
url: https://website.com/file.sh
```

and declare it in playbook like

```
  - name: Download file
    get_url:
      url: {{$url}}
      dest: /tmp/file.sh
      mode: 0777
```

I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: You may want to spend some time with the Ansible documentation.  In particular, the [Playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html) documentation has examples of defining and using variables.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can use vars option in the playbook like below

```
---
- name: Play
  hosts: HOST01
  vars:
    url: https://website.com/file.sh
  tasks:
     - name: Download file
       get_url:
         url: {{ url }}
         dest: /tmp/file.sh
         mode: 0777
...
```

2) Use 'set_fact' module provided by ansible

```
  tasks:
     - name : Setting the variable url
       set_fact:
         url: https://website.com/file.sh
     - name: Download file
       get_url:
         url: {{ url }}
         dest: /tmp/file.sh
         mode: 0777
```

Comment: Are both of these constant? I.e. the value cannot be changed once defined?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the ansible docs you will find the section Passing Variables On The Command Line, that give this sample:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars "version=1.23.45 other_variable=foo"
```

This is how you can pass variable to your playbook, Other way is to use **Jinja** templating, you have to read it in detail, this is also present in ansible documentation.